# How can I keep the same behaviour of navbar-collapse when navbar is fixed to top?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap 3.3.6.
My navigation has submenus, too (3 nav levels). All menues open correct in mobile views as long as I don't add navbar-fixed-top.
With navbar-fixed-top the height of navbar-collapse is set to 340px by default. With any changes of this CSS rule, it does not open and scroll as it does without navbar-fixed-top anymore. I prefer not to have a max-height. Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post your html/css

Answer (score 0):

how about use regular CSS on it

```
style="position: fixed;"
```

Although you can use a Bootstrap 'navbar-fixed-top' to embed 3 other navbar you have to make it act as a parent that fixes its child on top.